# How to check string inequality in s:if in Struts2

Tags: string, jsp, struts2

I am using `<s:if>` tag of Struts2 in one of the jsp-s. It is something like this:

```
<s:if test="%{#request.STATUS.equals('SINGLE')}">
    ...
    ...
</s:if>
```

It works fine. Now below this code, I want to write a code which will work only when status is not single. So I used

```
<s:if test="!(%{#request.STATUS.equals('SINGLE')})">
    ...
    ...
</s:if>
```

But this does not work. I also tried,

```
<s:if test="!%{#request.STATUS.equals('SINGLE')}">
    ...
    ...
</s:if>
```

This is a small issue, but don't know why it is not working. I want to know how string inequality can be done in `s:if` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Compare a String Like:

```
<c:if test="%{#request.STATUS!='SINGLE'}">
......</br>
......<br />
</c:if>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
<s:if test="%{#variable=='String 1'}">
   This is String 1
</s:if>
```